# Issue with Reading a File Using Relative Path in Python

Tags: python, pycharm, relative-path, working-directory

I'm currently working on a Python script named `bilin_intpol.py` which is located in the `/HW` directory on my system. The script needs to read an image file named `lenna.png` that is located in the `/code` directory.

I attempted to load the image using OpenCV with the following line of code:

```
img = cv2.imread('../code/lenna.png')
```

However, I'm encountering an issue where the image cannot be read using this relative path. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Following is my directory:

[image]

And here is the code:

[image]

Has anyone faced a similar issue or does anyone know why the relative path might not be working in this context? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's the working directory? what IDE do you use? have you checked with `os.path.exists()` ? it's not an opencv problem.

Comment: you're probably in another path - display the current directory with `print(os.getcwd())` .. additionally, to help yourself and the community, do not post text as images